# OpenGLUT: Texture for a sphere: what's the correct way to do it?

Tags: geometry, textures, glut

I need to give texture to an sphere: but I want to learn a good way to do it: I read methods which seem not to take advantage of the glut, they only use gl features. Maybe I am trying something unavailable, but I want to call solidsphere and generate the coordinates, I have load the .bmp, but the image don't want to rotate when the solid sphere is rotating, instead, the image (a face) always is facing the screen, as if it is "floating" in the surface. How can I stick it to the solid?? Thanks a bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, I got It: instead of calling to the glutSolidSphere, it must be employed the gluSphere, and call to the gluQuadricTexture. Then the face stays in its position, and we can rotate the camera view (with the function gluLookAt) around it and evaluate all the texture wrapping the solid.

Comment: Congrats on the fix.  You should accept your answer when you are able so that others will be able to learn from your success.  Cheers~